# PigeonHole proof - 8 Points Circle Radius 1

Tags: proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

I am asked to proof the following :
Using the pigeonhole principle, prove that among any 8 points on a circle of radius 1, there are at least two points whose distance is less than 1.

Just by using a drawing it seems logical, but i am having issues formally writing it, I am getting confused, i did a proof without using the pigeonhole saying :

Let's take the maximum angle in which we can separate the 8 points which is : $\frac{360}{8}=45$, convert 45 degrees to radian we get 0.7... we know that the segment linking any of those two points will be less than 0.7 so less than 1.

But i can not find a way to use pigeonhole.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You may partition the circle into $7$ half-open arcs (each including one endpoint), each arc subtends $360^\circ/7$ at the centre of the circle. Within each partition, any two points have distance less than $1$ between them.

By the pigeonhole principle, at least $2$ of the $8$ points are in the same partition.

Comment: Why 7 arcs? I am still confused

Comment: @Ravinala I chose $7$ partitions to apply the pigeonhole principle. I may also choose $6$ partitions (each arc subtends $60^\circ$), then in each partition any two points have distance just less than $1$.